# npm install fails on Windows 10 (node-gyp rebuild)

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, node-gyp

I'm trying to do a npm install for a cloned project that uses nodejs and node-gyp. Experienced a lot of version mismatch issues (especially with Visual Studio) and got to a point where node-gyp rebuild fails on rebuild.

Installed Python 2.7, uninstalled VS2013 and installed VS2015 Community edition with Visual C++ 2015. Changed the environment variable `GYP_MSVS_VERSION` to `2015` using `SET GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2015`, did `npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global`, ran `npm install -g --msvs_version=2015` and got the following errors. Nothing I did moved the process further at this point and have been trying for 5+ hours!

I'm using Cmder (running as administrator), npm v3.6.0, node v5.7.0 and node-gyp v3.3.1 (running `node-gyp -v` results in `v3.3.1`).

I'm on Windows 10 x64.

Anyone has any idea what's causing these errors?

```
..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc(231): error C2660: 'v8::Isolate::New': function does not take 0 arguments [C:\Users \ramtin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\troop-node-enforcer\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThr eads.vcxproj]
..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc(540): warning C4996: 'node::FatalException': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\ramt in\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\troop-node-enforcer\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads. vcxproj]
  C:\Users\ramtin\.node-gyp\5.7.0\include\node\node.h(282): note: see declaration of 'node::FatalException'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ramtin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\troop-node-enforcer\node_modules\webworker-threads
gyp ERR! node -v v5.7.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok
C:\Users\ramtin\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /troop-node-enforcer/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.8
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "--msvs_version=2015"
npm ERR! node v5.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! webworker-threads@0.5.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the webworker-threads@0.5.7 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the webworker-threads package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs webworker-threads
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls webworker-threads
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ramtin\trooptraining\troop\troop-node-enforcer\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

Comment: The story is long: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10768

Comment: @RomanDibikhin That's unrelated to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the version of `troop-node-enforcer` being installed is depending on an older version of the `webworker-threads` module which is outdated. The npm log shows it installing v0.5.7 whereas the newest version is v0.7.1 and has had many fixes since the older version.

Comment: I can't change the code (dependencies) for troop-node-enforcer, what can I do to overcome this problem?

Comment: Downgrading `node` to version `0.12.7` worked, but your solution would have worked if I could have upgrade `webworker-threads`.